# Terraform - Dynamic block to loop through list of objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, loops, dynamic, terraform

I'm trying to have this Terraform configured so that all someone needs to do to add a new SG ingress rule is to add a block to the `.tfvars` file, and the new ingress rule will be added to the single SG.

I have a `.tfvars` file that looks like this:

```
rules = [
  {
    protocol = "tcp"
    port = 22
    cidr = ["10.0.0.0/8"],
  },
  {
    protocol = "tcp"
    port = 80
    cidr = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
  },
  {
    protocol = "tcp"
    port = 443
    cidr = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
  },
  {
    protocol = "icmp"
    port = -1
    cidr = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
  }
]
```

And my Terraform is:

```
variable "rules" {
  type = list(object({
    protocol = string
    port = number
    cidr = list(string)
  }))
  description = "Specify the protocol, port range, and CIDRs."
}


resource "aws_security_group" "this" {
...

dynamic "ingress" {
  for_each = { for rule in var.rules : rule.id => rule }

  content {
    from_port   = var.rules.port
    to_port     = var.rules.port
    protocol    = var.rules.protocol
    cidr_blocks = var.rules.cidr
  }
}

...
```

I've tried to loop through the above, and also with using `for_each = var.rules` but I just get the following error (occurs for each of the below):

```
protocol     = var.rules.protocol
from_port    = var.rules.port
to_port      = var.rules.port
cidr_blocks  = var.rules.cidr
-----------------------------
var.rules is list of object with 4 elements. 
This value does not have any attributes.`
```

I'm a bit stuck and not sure what else to try, so does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. The first is in your `for_each` meta-argument value `for` expression lambda, you are attempting to access a non-existent object key of `id`. Also, you can easily just use a `list(object)` here instead of a `map(object)` like you are trying to do in your transformation, and then your input variable can be used directly. We can discard those and fix the value accordingly:

```
for_each = var.rules
```

The second issue is that your temporary lambda iterator variable in a dynamic block is the name of the block itself. In this case, your block is named `ingress`. Therefore, we need to access values from its object keys:

```
content {
  from_port   = ingress.value.port
  to_port     = ingress.value.port
  protocol    = ingress.value.protocol
  cidr_blocks = ingress.value.cidr
}
```

Combining these fixes, we arrive at:

```
dynamic "ingress" {
  for_each = var.rules

  content {
    from_port   = ingress.value.port
    to_port     = ingress.value.port
    protocol    = ingress.value.protocol
    cidr_blocks = ingress.value.cidr
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining, Matt. I forgot that I had removed my "id" variable as I no longer needed it, so thanks for explaining that. 
I have tried your suggested answer, but I just receive several errors saying `This object does not have an attribute named "cidr"/"protocol"/"port".`
You mention a lambda iterator, but nothing in my Terraform has anything to do with Lambda?

Comment: @Mcar49 Yes I keep forgetting that `list(object)` values have to be accessed with `value.<key>` even though the only possibility is the value since there is no top-level key. Updating answer.

Comment: Unfortunately even with your updated answer, I still get the same error message.

Comment: Though your answer definitely helped enough! Just a minor syntax error, using `protocol    = ingress.value["protocol"]` works! Thanks for the help Matt!